# Asp.net Crop then sent file as a posted file to http handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I'm trying to Crop the Image, then take the result image And save in directory on the server return url of this image i need to send as a posted file to http handler(same thing like after we choosing file from dialog box,then it will converted as posted file so that we can get file name and file content).And i dont have a chance to edit http handler i need to send croped imge url as a posted file.

Please help me out.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery plugins to accomplish your task. as i am not done any kind of cropping, but i found a link which may help you.  though you can find many plugins for crop in Jquery. [Jquery crop plugins](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/12/24/7-jquery-plugins-to-deal-with-image-cropping/)

[Jquery - Asp.net Cropping Image and Saving.](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET)

Comment: Thanks for u r replay.i done cropping part.it is working properly and i am able to saveing the image on the server folder but same time i need to send this path to http handler.http handler accepts only context.request.files format.now i am unable to send in that format.because i am not using file uploader control.the image path getting dynamically from code behind.i dont have chance to edit http handler.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code I used to crop images through vb.net,but first you should download [this control](http://webcropimage.codeplex.com/):

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
    Font-Size="15pt">
    Upload your picture
    <br />
       <asp:Panel ID="croppnl" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="810px">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
        <cs:CropImage ID="CropImage1" runat="server" Image="image1" 
            IsInUpdatePanel="False" />
        <asp:Button ID="cropbtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
            Font-Names="Tahoma" Text="Crop" />
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
```

Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Image.jpg"
End Sub


Protected Sub cropbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cropbtn.Click
  CropImage1.Crop(MapPath("croppedpictures.jpg"))
End Sub
```